# Add groups as collaborator

Tags: box-api

I am trying to add a group as a collaborator of a folder using the BOX.net api but i can't.

I am not having any issues to add users, but i couldn't add groups.

I am doing it as they say to do it: {id: "GROUP_ID"} but i am getting a "NOT FOUND" error.

I checked the group and folder id and they are both correct.

Did anyone face this issue before? Is there somebody who can help me with this? I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Marcelo

Answer (score 1):

You have to be a group administrator on the Box Enterprise in order to manage groups.  You may need to ask your Box admin to add you as a co-admin, and give you the "manage groups" permission.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pass in "type":"group" in the accessible_by field in addition to "id":"GROUP_ID".

This should be documented soon.

Comment: Hello, 
I tried with that, also, but i couldn't make it work. I am getting the same error.
Any other option?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small example of adding a group as collaborator (PHP). This is done via the V2 API, in case you're using the V1 api (saw you mentioned box.net's api, which is the V1 api).

```
function addGroupColaborator($folderId, $groupId, $accessType, $accessToken){
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
        CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT    => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false
    );
    $url = 'https://api.box.com/2.0/collaborations?notify=false';
    $options[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = array ("Authorization: Bearer ".$accessToken);
    $postf = array(
            "item" => array(
                    "id"   => $folderId,
                    "type" => "folder"
            ),
            "accessible_by" => array(
                    "id"   => $groupId,
                    "type" => 'group'
            ),
            "role" => $accessType
    );
    $options[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
    $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = json_encode($postf);
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($result, true);
}
```